# How do I use Google Cloud API's via Anaconda Spyder?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I am pretty new to Python in general and recently started messing with the Google Cloud environment, specifically with the Natural Language API.

One thing that I just cant grasp is how do I make use of this environment, running scripts that use this API or any API from my local PC in this case my Anaconda Spyder environment?

I have my project setup, but from there I am not exactly sure, which steps are necessary. Do I have to include the authentication somehow in the Script inside Spyder?

Some insights would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the [quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/quickstart), you should specify the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS in your command line according to your Operating System. So, if you're using Linux (or Mac OSX), open your shell and type:

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="[PATH]"
```

But, if you're using Windows, then use PowerShell:

```
$env:GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="[PATH]"
```

You can also explicitly specify your credentials in your Python code like [this](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#auth-cloud-explicit-python):

```
def explicit():
    from google.cloud import storage

    # Explicitly use service account credentials by specifying the private key
    # file.
    storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json(
        'service_account.json')

    # Make an authenticated API request
    buckets = list(storage_client.list_buckets())
    print(buckets)
```

Answer (score -1):

First install the API by pip install or conda install in the scripts directory of anaconda and then simply import it into your code and start coding.

Comment: I guess my main issue is the authentication part as I am not understanding correctly where the referenced commands from the documentation need to be used. For example where to I run the export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS command. If I try to run it in the Cloud SDK consol I get export command not found

Comment: You need to download the json credentials file then use the export command in a Linux shell on the same machine you have spyder installed.